# MediaWIki primaryauthenticationprovider

Tags: mediawiki

How to create a **primaryauthenticationprovider** that autocreates the user?I need know how to make it. Any simple code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the username with a pass response, and it will be autocreated if it does not exist.

Comment: I dont know how to do it because no examples anywhere.